# Different behaviour of margin-left in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have an issue with two different browsers. I have attached snapshots of issues:
When I use the following css I get image1:

```
.support-data-text img, .support-data-text select {
float:left
}
/* this is for dropdown list */
form#saveSupport select {
    height: 29px;
    width: 234px;
    position: absolute;
}

form#saveSupport input{float: left; width: 243px;}

/* this is for the img we are using for dropdown list */
form#saveSupport .select_game { background: url(../images/select-status.png) no-repeat;
   width: 223px; position: absolute; height: 29px; line-height:29px;
   padding: 0 0 0 10px; color: #333; font-size:12px; overflow: hidden; 
}
```

[image]

and when i add `margin-left: 18%` to `form#saveSupport .select_game` Chrome shows proper alignment of dropdown list image but not the actual dropdown list whereas Firefox displace the drodown list to right side. (Image2) [image]

Kindly help me with the solution. I would be thankful!

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: Can you provide a working url to test this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you set `position:relative` to parent element and for child element set `position:relative`

I think your Parent Div is this

```
.support-data-text{
position:relative;
}
```

and now set to child div absolute position and set to **left right top bottom** according to your design .

Comment: this will cause more trouble I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the CSS properties acts differently in both Chrome and Firefox.To fix this I used the below solution which worked for me. Add the CSS properties which acts differently in chrome and firefox inside class(same class name which use for chrome css prop as well)  which should come under @supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar). The properties which we add within @supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar) will be taken only for Firefox browser.

Example:

```
@supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar) {
  .yourclassname {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    bottom: 2px;
  }
}
```